# Bathymetry map (DEM) and the reservoir Volume from bathymetry points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, bathymetry, volume

Could anyone provide me with a workflow from POINTS --> Bathymetry map (DEM) and  Volume calculation in ArcGIS?

I would like to create a bathymetry map (DEM) and calculate the volume for a large riverine reservoir (Lake Diefenbaker). I have the bathymetry depth points.

The first issue is how can I restrict the interpolation area to the shoreline areas?

Because points are along the river valley which it divides into a fork at the end (T shape reservoir, attached photo), I can’t simply create a TIN surface without creating a boundary around the points.

[image]

Comment: What are you using? ArcMap, QGIS etc?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.5. Is QGIS better, is it free?

Comment: QGIS is free, but with ArcGIS 10.5 you should have no problems let me write up an answer

Comment: Why not create a polygon around your line shapefiles there following the shape, the use raster interpolation http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/understanding-interpolation-analysis.htm, and then Data management-> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Clip to extract the study area?

Comment: Thanks John, I will give it a shot and get back to you if I have problems with it.

Comment: I finally managed to create DEM from bathymetry points and calculate the volume, but the output does not make sense. I guess I need to modify the units or coordinates. I don't know how. Here is the output (My input surface is the elevations of the bed in meters above sea level (m asl) in GCS_WGS_1984 and decimal degrees and my Plane Height is the reservoir full supply level (FSL) which is 556.87 m asl:
Plane_Height, Reference, Z_Factor, Area_2D, Area_3D, Volume
556.87, BELOW, 1.00, 0.053866900608273, 126.88623569244, 1.3850421777189